# Which video game do Underwood and Yates play in chapter 33?

Tags: house-of-cards

In *House of Cards* chapter 33 (episode 7 of season 3), there is a scene where writer Tom Yates seems to introduce a new video game to Frank Underwood. This is not Monument Valley (that appears in a previous episode). What game is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The game being played is called [The Stanley Parable](http://www.stanleyparable.com/). Here is a YouTube video of the scene:

<sup>[This conversation also happened on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/stanleyparable/comments/2xdod4/kevin_spacey_playing_the_stanley_parable_in_house/)... [and this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/HouseOfCards/comments/2xc15m/chapter_33_house_of_cards_season_3_episode_7/).</sup>

Comment: One extra fact: it's that Frank Underwood in his representative's time, he used to play Call of Duty and God of War, I think is the third part.